# Comparisson (less than/greater than) not working in google script

Tags: google-apps-script

It seems like a very simple problem, but I cannot seem to figure out the problem. I am using google forms to run an inventory system and have made a system to correct the counts. They input into the form what the correct count should be and to adjust the value my script compares the old count vs the new count. There are two formulas for if the new value is higher than, or less than the previous value. Most of the time this works great, but there are other times when it suddenly will believe the new number (that is much higher than the old) is less than the previous value. Even running logs will show that it has said 12 is greater than 100, or 9 is greater than 50. I do not know why it is doing this.

Here is my if statement:

```
 if(!hfw){ 
    var test = responses.getRange("C"+(lastRow)).getValues();
    var test2 = current.getRange("DH9").getValues();
    if(test == test2) {
      current.getRange("DH6").setValue("0");
    };
    if(test > test2){
      current.getRange("DH6").setValue(test-test2);
    };
    if(test < test2){
      current.getRange("DH6").setValue("-"+(test2-test));
    };
  }
```

Here is the adjustment sheet with the form and script: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/188fv1qfHn6X3kWOyKoYJ_pALCaXwVMsOXWi5I2aiccg/edit?usp=sharing

Anything will help. You can see in the last line I did 50 across the board and from 1-6 it worked fine, then 7-11 it decided they were greater than 50 and did the second equation.

The page that is edited is here: Sheet11
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sp12diuzqzxZR4Un548J8h4pCCOMO_jwa0XmdL0bsTI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) *(note: plural)* returns arrays.  When you [compare objects in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness), you are comparing addresses of the objects in memory, not values of the object.  In other words, it's probably random whether the array `test` is less than or greater than `test2`, and they will never be equal.

You need to use `.getValue()` *(note: singular)*, to get just a single value to compare, and you should be careful that you end up comparing numbers and not strings (by default, Sheets should do that conversion for you, but you can override that in various ways).